# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) trying to return swal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I am trying to conditional rendering when state is undefined, and i would like to show a sweetalert to show the user that he has not selected a client. But i am receiving this error:

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Snippet:

```
const location = useLocation();

const ClientNotSelected = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Deleted!',
                            'Your file has been deleted.',
                            'success'
                        )
                    }
                })

            }

        </div>

    )
}


if (location.state === undefined) {
    return <ClientNotSelected />;
}
```

Comment: Consider converting `ClientNotSelected` into an async function, and awaiting `Swal.fire`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for your comment, but the problem is still here.

Comment: It wasn’t an answer. May you make sure the example given is complete? Otherwise the issue may lie elsewhere in the codebase. See [mcve] for more info

Comment: well, I am trying to move between routes passing through react-router <Link an state. So in the component i want to check if location.state is empty so i render an alert. That's everything but I think I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create and render a component to fire the alert.

You can move `Swal.fire()` to your if statement.

Like this:

```
if (location.state === undefined) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If write it like that react ask me about the return, then if i write the return i go back to the main problem

Comment: Can you describe what error React is throwing?

Comment: sure, [Image link](https://gyazo.com/adfc85527710e9ee4b3b182d2e2ce07e)

Comment: It seems that you are still trying to render a component to fire the alert.

Can you try with the snippet above and describe if it works and if there is any error?

Comment: Yes, that was i was talking about: [link-image](https://gyazo.com/40024e013704af11c595e65efca7ecdf)

Comment: Did you create a component just for using the alert?
If so, you can fire the alert inside the parent component without creating another one.

Comment: I just created it because i want to conditional rendering depending on the state if its undefined i want to show the user an alert, even i can show normal alert an send the user back but i would like to do it with swal, anyway if i can't i will use normal alert.

Comment: You can still fire the alert conditionally, but you don't need another component to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your comm i've finally fixed it in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

**HOW I SOLVED IT:**

I have created

```
const [clientSelected, setClientSelected] = useState(false);
```

and i checked it in the useEffect, with swal.fire inside here it doesnt give any problems/errors

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (location.state === undefined){
        setClientSelected(false);
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                history.goBack();
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        setClientSelected(true);
    }
})
```

below i have continued with the same condition but checking the new var clientSelected

```
if (!clientSelected) {
    return <h1>Select a client</h1>;
} else {
    return <Component />;
}
```